# Custom Post Type - Permalink Problem

Tags: plugins

I am having a hard time implementing a custom post type correctly. I have searched for a solution for a long time but couldn't find any. Here's what I did:

1. Freshly installed WordPress in my local wamp server (enabled apache rewrite_module first).
2. Using default theme (twenty fourteen). No plugins installed.
3. Changed permalinks to "Post name"
4. In the plugins folder, created a folder named pr_custom_posts and inside that, created a file named pr_custom_posts.php. In the file I created a custom post type. The code is as follows:

   ```
   /*
   * Plugin Name: PR Movies Custom Post
   * Plugin URI: http://www.example.com
   * Description: Learning Custom Posts
   * Author: PR
   * Author URI: http://www.example.com
   * Version: 1.0
   */

   class PR_Movies_Custom_Post {

   public function __construct() {
       $this->register_post_type();
       //flush_rewrite_rules();
   }

   public function register_post_type () {
       $args = array(
           'labels' => array (
               'name' => 'Movies',
               'singular_name' => 'Movie',
               'add_new' => 'Add New Movie',
               'add_new_item' => 'Add New Movie',
               'edit_item' => 'Edit Movie',
               'new_item' => 'Add New Movie',
               'view_item' => 'View Movie',
               'search_items' => 'Search Movies',
               'not_found' => 'No Movies Found',
               'not_found_in_trash' => 'No Movies Found in Trash'
           ),
           'query_var' => 'movies',
           'rewrite' => array (
               'slug' => 'movies/',
               'with_front'=> false
           ),
           'public' => true,
           'publicly_queryable' => true,
           'has_archive' => true,
           'menu_position' => 10,
           'menu_icon' => admin_url().'/images/media-button-video.gif',
           'supports' => array (
               'title',
               'thumbnail',
               'editor'
           )
       );
       register_post_type('pr_movie', $args);
       //flush_rewrite_rules();
   }
   }

    add_action('init', function() {
   new PR_Movies_Custom_Post();
   //flush_rewrite_rules();
    });
   ```

The Good Thing: The CPT is showing in my admin panel and I can add and view movies there.

THE PROBLEM: I cannot preview the movies in the front end (By clicking the "view" in the CPT in admin panel). It shows in the front end only when I set permalink to default (`http://localhost/wp02/?p=123`).

What I have tried:

1. Go to permalink, keep permalink settings to "Post name" and Save changes.
2. Use flush_rewrite_rules() in several places (one by one) in my code. Please see the commented out parts in the code above.
3. Created a menu item as:
   URL: `http://localhost/wp02/movies`
   Navigation Label: Movies
   This creates a menu item in the front end but shows "Not Found" when "Movies" link is clicked.

This is driving me crazy. Can anyone please help on this? I would really appreciate.

Comment: Why you've added / in rewrite slug, replace that slash after movies and reflush the rewrite rules and you are good to go.

Comment: @Anjum Thanks for your perfect solution. I was following a tutorial where / was added in the rewrite slug. Thanks again.

Comment: @Anjum please post that as an answer, so it can be properly accepted and visible as such :)

Answer (score -1):

Thanks to Anjum for his suggestion in the comments. The problem has been solved by removing the front-slash in the rewrite slug. The error was caused by:

```
'rewrite' => array (
    'slug' => 'movies/',
    'with_front'=> false
),
```

The error has been solved by the following modification:

```
'rewrite' => array (
    'slug' => 'movies',
    'with_front'=> false
),
```